# PHP - Filter Non Numerals from a string

Tags: php

I have a variable:

```
$number
```

that could contain values in these formats:

```
125.00
125.00
$125.00
```

I need to insert this as a number only into a database, so I need to remove/filter out anything that isn't a number whilst retaining the decimals points.

Not sure how/best approach to do this in PHP?

Comment: I would allow the user only to add certain kinds of values. So if anything other than `[0-9] . $` is in the String, I would send an error to the user that he has to input the amount in Dollars only. Once that is made sure (`preg_match(/^\$?[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/), you can remove any `$` sign by str_replace or even safer by preg_replace at beginning of String. Otherwise you could risk replacing `20$50` to 2050.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex :

```
<?php
$num = "125.00";
$num = preg_replace("/([^0-9\.,])/","",$num);
$num = (double) $num; // Make it to double to allow point and comma
$num = (int) $num; // And then convert it into an integer
echo $num;
?>
```

Comment: I've tried this code and it's returning "25". Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry my bad xD. I have update my answer. Please check